# Is there a need for multiple insert scripts when handling multiple form data?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

When creating an insert statement for a HTML form that is stored in a database. Do i have to create multiple insert scripts to handle multiple forms or is there a better way to handle the data using one script.

```
<?php 

include 'includes/mysqli_connect.php';

$title = $_POST ['title'];
$fname =$_POST ['first_name' ];
$lname =$_POST ['last_name'];
$c_status = $_POST ['customer_status'];
$addr1 = $_POST ['address_line1'];
$addr2 = $_POST ['address_line2'];
$town = $_POST ['address_town'];
$county = $_POST ['address_county'];
$post_code = $_POST ['post_code'];
$mob_tel = $_POST ['mobile_tel'];
$hom_tel = $_POST ['home_tel'];
$email = $_POST ['email'];
$date_join = $_POST ['date_joined'];


$q = "INSERT INTO customer (title, first_name, last_name, customer_status, address_line1, address_line2, address_town, 
    address_county, post_code, mobile_tel, home_tel, email, date_joined) VALUES ('$title', '$fname', '$lname', '$c_status', 
    '$addr1', '$addr2', '$town', '$county', '$post_code', '$mob_tel', '$hom_tel', '$email', '$date_join')";

    $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc,$q);  // NB result $r = true if insert worked.

    if ($r) echo "<p>A new customer has been added to the database</p>\n";
    else {  // There's been an error
        $sqlerr = mysqli_error($dbc); // Retrieves error message
        echo '<p class="error">Error - failed to insert record. <br />'.
                 'Error reported by MySQL is '.$sqlerr.'<br />Query = '.$q."</p>\n";
    }
?>
```

My query is there a better way to handle multiple forms using the same script. Is it simply the case of repeating the insert statements for each form, or shall i create a new script for each form.

Comment: Post the code or form

Comment: Why are you using multiple forms to begin with if they're all being processed at the same location? You can just use one form for that.

Comment: I have created multiple forms for multiple tables in the database. Example, i have a customer form = for a customer table. An appliance table for entering new appliances. All these forms are located on different pages of the website.

Comment: You're going to need something for each form since they're all different, but I think you want to save yourself from typing a lot of stuff, so why not use a switch to build your needed query?

Comment: Thank you for your help, if any has any examples of how they would code a switch statement for multiple queries.